# connecting an iOS app to a hosted website on a local network with SQL Server backend

Tags: mysql, objective-c, sql-server, xcode, lightswitch-2013

my scenario is as follows.. I have a completed Visual Studio Lightswitch HTML Client website hosted locally which uses SQL Server as the backend. I also have an iOS app which currently stores everything locally. (for this example lets say it saves barcodes)

when I scan a barcode it saves to the MySQL database on the Apple Device locally and cannot be taken off the device without plugging it into my machine.

this is where I need some help/advice... how can i join these both together so the app saves the information onto the server (i know it should not be done directly) but I am unsure on how to do this via web services on a local network)

Thanks guys for any help, I have a general understanding of HTML/CSS but no experience in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a WebAPI so that your app can post the data, take a look at this example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2013/04/22/create-dashboard-reports-with-lightswitch-webapi-and-serverapplicationcontext.aspx

Also keep in mind that because you are running localhost your app is going to find it difficult to see it, because your app won't be able to see `http://localhost`

Maybe you could publish your site to a free Windows Azure trial site so you can interact with it

Comment: its not running on http://localhost, it has its own url on the network so thats not an issue, thanks for the tip, ill look into this soon